# Why do I get an error using pywinauto in Python to record video?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pywinauto

I was trying to implement the Python code to record using Windows camera given by
mjdargen.

```py
import pywinauto
import time
import subprocess
import os
import datetime

def win_record(duration):
    subprocess.run('start microsoft.windows.camera:', shell=True)  # open camera app

    # focus window by getting handle using title and class name
    # subprocess call opens camera and gets focus, but this provides alternate way
    # t, c = 'Camera', 'ApplicationFrameWindow'
    # handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=t, class_name=c)[0]
    # # get app and window
    # app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=handle)
    # window = app.window(handle=handle)
    # window.set_focus()  # set focus
    time.sleep(2)  # have to sleep

    # take control of camera window to take video
    desktop = pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia")
    cam = desktop['Camera']
    # cam.print_control_identifiers()
    # make sure in video mode
    if cam.child_window(title="Switch to Video mode", auto_id="CaptureButton_1", control_type="Button").exists():
        cam.child_window(title="Switch to Video mode", auto_id="CaptureButton_1", control_type="Button").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # start then stop video
    cam.child_window(title="Take Video", auto_id="CaptureButton_1", control_type="Button").click()
    time.sleep(duration+2)
    cam.child_window(title="Stop taking Video", auto_id="CaptureButton_1", control_type="Button").click()

    # retrieve vids from camera roll and sort
    dir = 'C:/Users/baksh/Pictures/Camera Roll'
    all_contents = list(os.listdir(dir))
    vids = [f for f in all_contents if "_Pro.mp4" in f]
    vids.sort()
    vid = vids[-1]
    # compute time difference
    vid_time = vid.replace('WIN_', '').replace('_Pro.mp4', '')
    vid_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(vid_time, '%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = now - vid_time
    # time different greater than 2 minutes, assume something wrong & quit
    if diff.seconds > 120:
        quit()
    
    subprocess.run('Taskkill /IM WindowsCamera.exe /F', shell=True)  # close camera app
    print('Recorded successfully!')


win_record(2)
```

https://gist.github.com/mjdargen/956cc968864f38bfc4e20c9798c7d670

It was working just fine till now. However, from today I have been getting error message as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baksh\Desktop\Text to Speech\Recorder.py", line 52, in <module>
    win_record(2)
  File "C:\Users\baksh\Desktop\Text to Speech\Recorder.py", line 29, in win_record
    cam.child_window(title="Take Video", auto_id="CaptureButton_1", control_type="Button").click()
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Users\baksh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Take Video', 'auto_id': 'CaptureButton_1', 'control_type': 'Button', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Camera', ApplicationFrameWindow, 1508998>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

I have searched the net countless times. I have tried to debug the code countless times, but to no avail. Could somebody please help me fix this problem?